# Mac OS X: Including Stata file in R leads to error

Tags: r, stata

I'm running code that used to work on a different Macbook on a new one with

- `OS X` 10.9.5
- `R studio` 0.98.1083
- `R` just installed freshly (first via home-brew, now standard package)

I'm trying to open a `stata` file that contains German umlauts (special characters). Opening it in Rstudio under Windows worked normally.

Now I try to include that file:

```
library(foreign)
basis <- read.dta("myfile.dta", convert.factors =NA)[LL_basis]
Error in factor(rval[[v]], levels = tt[[ll[v]]], labels = names(tt[[ll[v]]])) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1
```

Alternatively, the following also fails

```
library(lattice)
library(MASS)
library(memisc)
basis <- as.data.frame(as.data.set(Stata.file("myfile.dta")))
Error in as.data.set(Stata.file("myfile.dta")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.set': Error in nchar(varlabs) : invalid multibyte string 4
```

Comment: convert.factors takes a boolean, i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Not sure if this is your problem, but it is a place to start. Try: `basis <- read.dta("myfile.dta", convert.factors = FALSE)`

Comment: Mac versions of R built with homebrew are known to be fragile. Read the R-admin guide for details.  Unless you are much more experienced than most of us, you should use the binary R packages.

Comment: I see. I was only doing so because the download link on the website was broken for me: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.1.1-mavericks.pkg

Comment: I just installed the standard package for OS X > 10.5 and I receive the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following question was related: [Error in nchar() when reading in stata file in R on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669911/error-in-nchar-when-reading-in-stata-file-in-r-on-mac)

The error is apparently coming from neither `Stata.file` nor `read.dta`. Neither have an `encoding=latin1` option. However, adding the following at the beginning of the file fixed the issue:

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')
```

Comment: Accept your own answer!

Comment: Perhaps someone comes up with a better answer. I don't like that this requires to set up the locale for the whole script, rather than  only for the next file to be read in.

Comment: Fair, although you can always save the old locale and then set it back.